# Where is "in honoring" or "to honor" more appropriate as an idiom?

Tags: grammar

> The practice of renaming a street Martin Luther King Boulevard has been adopted by many cities **in honoring/to honor** the civil rights leader.

Please give explanation.

Comment: Either *in honoring* or *to honor* works a good deal better here than calling the renaming a *practice;* for in each city it is presumably a one-time deal.

Comment: In general, when it comes to idioms, there is no explanation as to why one is more common than another, beyond the fact that more people use the one instead of the other.  Why do more people say "come in" rather than "enter"?  It just is.

Comment: You missed out ***in honour of***, which I suspect may be the most common form of all for such contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's usually either "to honor" or "in honor *of*" (and not "in honoring").

> Please give explanation

Just because that's what's idiomatic, I guess.

Maybe "to honor" implies something more timeless (even eternal), or a "perfect" tense, whereas "honoring" would imply a present continuous.

Comment: I guess it's just that I need to read more ??